Material Ui Datagrid unstable and grows in size
I am using Material Ui Datagrid like below. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The Datgrid gets unstable and grows indefinitely downwards with flickering pagesize at the bottom when Search button is clicked. Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you .
const [adUsers, setADUsers] = useState<IADUser[]>([]);

const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined);

const [showGrid, setShowGrid] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined);


const onSearchHandle = (e: any) => {
    if (validate()) {
        setShowLoader(true);
        let response: IADUser[];
        userStore.getAdUsers(searchText).then((data) => {
            setADUsers(data);
        });

        setShowLoader(false);
    } else {
        console.log("Validation failed");
    }
};

    useEffect(() => {
    if (showLoader == false) {
        setShowGrid(true);
    }
}, [showLoader]);

<div className="col table-responsive p-2">
                            {showGrid && (
                                <DataGrid
                                    getRowId={(row: IADUser) => row.rowId as number}
                                    rows={adUsers}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    initialState={{
                                        pagination: {
                                            paginationModel: {
                                                pageSize: 10,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    pageSizeOptions={[10]}
                                    disableRowSelectionOnClick
                                />
                            )}
                            {showLoader && <Spinner />}
                        </div>


setShowLoader(false); is in the wrong place for starters. It is being called after the userStore.getAdUsers() call in the code but not in reality. It should be in the .then(). Also, if (showLoader == false) setShowGrid(true); you are ping-ponging states, which is a code smell. Are you sure you need 2 states? I haven't run your code, because your question did not include an MRE

I have tried the above code and issue exists. I want to keep separate state variables to show/hide different elements.
